# CNN(neural network) for finding the supernova

Tags: deep-learning, astronomy, conv-neural-network

I'm a student major in physics as well as CS. One of my tasks is to find the supernova. The discovery of supernova is tedious and tough. 
Through contrast the picture now and before, then we may find some bright spot on the picture and that may be the supernova.
like this,
[image]
The picture has many noise, and there are always many ghost spot because of instability of the instruments, or other lights make the illusions.

However, the supernova has some obvious characteristics, it always show up around the fixed stars. The shape of light is circle. etc.There already some conventional methods used on that. But they don't have good performance.

**So I wonder if it's worthwhile trying it on CNN. 
Which kind of data can CNN do well on?**

Thanks.

Comment: I am pretty sure you have analyze image pixel by pixel and compare multiple images.

Comment: So does you task frame in an image classification scenario?

Comment: This is a very specific task (and each task is different) so it'll be hard to get much experience in for this question. Imo it's definitely *worth* doing both a CNN and a simpler algorithm with standard image processing techniques. Usually CNN is better at detection than localization but that's something that hasn't been observed on your dataset but colored real-world pictures - so who knows for certain, really.

Comment: At the end of the day it depends why you want to use a CNN. if you want to demonstrate advanced CS ability and an excuse to use CNNs then do it and learn from it. However, if you simply want to solve the problem in the most efficient manner (ie. if your main concern is physics not CS) then just keep it simple

Answer (score 1):

> So I wonder if it's worthwhile trying it on CNN.

*I think CNN is overkill for this problem.*

> Which kind of data can CNN do well on?

*Data with complex localised relationships in the structure and a large number of features. You use a convolution across a local frame to learn the representation.*

The problem you have is very simple. You don't have many parameters, i.e. colour is grayscale, representation of a supernova is all contained within the immediate vicinity of it's occurrence.

I think you would probably have much more success with some really simple algorithm such as:

- Find all fixed stars
- search for any big 'blobs' of light with specific parameters
- search for any circles of light

These alone will massively reduce the computational size of the problem. From there, there are a number of ML approaches you could take.

CNNs are generally for very big data sets with highly complex non-linear relationships. This (may?) be a big data set but it is certainly not complex in this particular task.

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think MNIST holds *that* much more complex relationships than his dataset. Intuitively, I wouldn't rule out CNNs that easily although you're also right in saying that this can probably be solved with simple image processing techniques. It probably depends on the amount of noise and variance in his dataset. If it's high, it'll be hard to keep hand-crafted heuristics robust. Otherwise a simple solution is the best.

Comment: I agree but MNIST can be solved pretty well with an autoencoder to about 97% accuracy. Plus his data is simply logistic regression. also think about the problem in context. In physics you don't really need *every* supernova as you're already dealing with a tiny subset of data. Missing 3% for the sake of 2 weeks of work is more than acceptable. If you want the extra 3% worth of supernovas you can always just get a slightly larger sample image as there's always more sky to sample!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, I got this idea because of the new project raised by Astronomy Club. It calls on the public to find the supernova. So I believe there must exist some features. Since our human can find them, so do the machine. But the conventional methods can't do well on extracting features,  I turn to the CNN. Expecting this network can extract the information itself. And my teacher advised me to prepare this for my final project of ml class.  I'd like to have a try. Can you give me some tricks for this and the key points I should pay attention to ?

Comment: Use python's theano library and try get access to an NVIDIA graphics card so you can use CUDA. See deeplearning.net for information on theano and sample code